# how to get value on stdClass php

Tags: php

how to get value on stdClass php, how to get data 10002286  on stdclass

> stdClass Object ( [return_code] => 00 [return_message] => sukses
>   [user_profile] => stdClass Object ( [telkomid] => rohimfikri
>   [account_id] => 10002286 [full_name] => Fikri Rohim s ) )

how to get value on telkomid?

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])){  
$config=array('client_id' =>'xxx',
        'client_secret' => 'xxx',
        'redirect_uri' =>'http://xxx',
        'code' =>$_GET['code']
    );
    $temanDev = new TemanDev($config);
    $temanDev->getAccessToken();

    $profile=$temanDev->getUserProfile('public');
        $service=$temanDev->getUserServices('public');
    print_r($profile);  
        print_r($service);  

}
echo $object->user_profile->telkomid;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`echo $object->user_profile->account_id;`

Comment: not working

this is my code
if (isset($_GET['code'])){  
$config=array('client_id' =>'xxxx',
  'client_secret' => 'xxx',
  'redirect_uri' =>'http://xxxxx',
  'code' =>$_GET['code']
 );
 $temanDev = new TemanDev($config);
 $temanDev->getAccessToken();
 
 $profile=$temanDev->getUserProfile('public');
        $service=$temanDev->getUserServices('public');
 print_r($profile); 
        print_r($service); 
   
}
echo $object->user_profile->telkomid;

Comment: Here $object refers to variable name which contains the stdclass object. You need to use proper variable name.

Comment: Either `$profile->user_profile->account_id` or `$service->user_profile->account_id`